# json conversion rename field in object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, get

I have an array of Object  that contain a string array. The object is filled dynamically and returns a value such as the following:

[image]

But when I invoke the Get, the answer has the changed label:

[image]

Having to use the field on an angular data-binding, I can not use the field that presents <> because it sends wrong interpretation.

Why replaces the label and how do I fix?

PS.I read similar questions that bring to a serialization problem but I do not explicitly set it in API and honestly do not know how it works.

as required:

```
namespace Controllers
{
    public class CController : ApiController
    {

        [HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetAll_FullDetail()
        {
            try
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new CategoryDA().GetAll_FullDetail());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you using webforms Asp.NET?

Comment: Excuse me but I am a newbie on the subject, but I think to answer correctly telling you that use asp.net MVC. Should have misunderstood the question, I need to explain better what you mean to me.

Comment: I'm italian too ... :-) ... can you post the code of your controller?

Comment: I had guessed: federico :)

Comment: Do you use Newtonsoft for Json serialization? ... i suggest also to you (but it's not the solution for your problem) to respond with IHttpAcionResult from the api... like 
        [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult GetAll_FullDetail()
        {
            try
            {
                return Ok(new CategoryDA().GetAll_FullDetail());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return  InternalServerError(ex);
            }
        }

Comment: I don't use Newtonsoft, I guess . Why suggest IHttpActionResult?

Comment: this is maybe why the json don't look as you aspect ..try to use NewtonSoft ... set it in your webApiConfig.cs..like this 
            var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().First();
            jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
            // jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore;
            jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();

Comment: I suggest IHttpAcionResult cause it's more easy and friendly to use..and Rest Compliance for the response..but it's my idea